# Create a frequency table from a specific dataframe with comma separate strings

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
df <- structure(list(doc_id = c("1", "2"), ner_words = c("John, Google", 
"Amazon, Python, Canada")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How is it possible to make a `table(df$ner_words)` but take as different words in every row? Example of expected result

```
data.frame(text = c("John", "Google", "Amazon", "Python", "Canada"), frq = c(1,1,1,1,1))
```

Comment: Perhaps try: `as.data.frame(table(unlist(strsplit(df$ner_words, ","))))`

Answer (score 1):

This is one option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(ner_words, sep = ", ") %>% 
  group_by(ner_words) %>% 
  transmute(ner_words, frq = n())

# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Groups:   ner_words [5]
  ner_words   frq
  <chr>     <int>
1 John          1
2 Google        1
3 Amazon        1
4 Python        1
5 Canada        1
```

Answer (score 1):

`separate_rows()` and then `count()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(ner_words) %>%
  count(ner_words, name = "frq")

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   ner_words   frq
#   <chr>     <int>
# 1 Amazon        1
# 2 Canada        1
# 3 Google        1
# 4 John          1
# 5 Python        1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_extract` and `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   transmute(ner_words = str_extract_all(ner_words, '\\w+')) %>% 
   unnest(c(ner_words)) %>%
   count(ner_words)
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  ner_words     n
#* <chr>     <int>
#1 Amazon        1
#2 Canada        1
#3 Google        1
#4 John          1
#5 Python        1
```